# How to get a contour command triggered automatically in a loop?

Tags: python, time, contour

I want to get a sort of contour animation in a Python program using time. The following program does not allow such an animation. It produces 3 independent plots! Any help would be highly appreciated. Thank you! 
Please here is the program:

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import time

n=11
x = np.linspace(0,1,n)
y = np.linspace(0,1,n)
X,Y = np.meshgrid(x,y)

u=np.zeros((n,n))

t = time.time()
max_framerate = 10
for m in range(3): 
    for i in range(n):
        for j in range(n):
            u[i,j]=x[i]*y[j]*(m+1)

    CS = plt.contour(X, Y, u)
    plt.clabel(CS, inline=1, fontsize=10)
    plt.title('Velocity contour')
    plt.show()

    while time.time() - t < (1./max_framerate): pass
    t = time.time()
```

Comment: I don't know anything about matplotlib or pyplot. However, if you are getting three independent plots, logically, you need to 'un-plot' the previous plot before drawing the current one (or, maybe do something like a plt.clear() if that exists, before setting up the new contour). Not sure if this helps at all - it was just an idea.

Comment: Thank you Peter for your comment. In fact, I put 3 plots just to illustrate the problem but I need to visualize the plot over many iterations! (100) I would like please to launch the plots automatically! Thanks!

Comment: It is possible that this may help: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3294989/color-plot-animation-with-play-pause-stop-cabability-using-tkinter-with-pylab]